# Carousel Product Cart Slider Change speed

Tags: performance, twitter-bootstrap, slider, carousel, product

Found product slider on this link

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-product-cart-slider#comments

It's excellent but I want to change time before it's slide,
because I don't have time to read the content.

This is the JavaScript I used

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('.carousel-inner .item').first().addClass('active');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind foud it :)

```
> <script>
> 
> jQuery(document).ready(function(){
>     jQuery('.carousel-inner .item').first().addClass('active');
>     jQuery('.carousel').carousel({interval: 15000}); });
> 
> </script>
```